# Obtener datos con WHERE_IN en CodeIgniter Enviando Array con Ajax desde la Vista

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter-3

No soy muy experto en tema estoy en los inicios. lo que quiero es obtener datos del modelo con un array enviado con los ID de categoria al controlador mediante una peticion AJAX, los ID de categoria agrupo en un array en Javascript de la siguiente manera:

```js
var categoriadata = new Array();
function filter(categoriad) {
if(categoriad>0){categoriadata.push(categoriad);}         $.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>productos/PaginacionData',
 data:'categoriadata='+categoriadata,
 success: function (html) {
  $('#productlist').html(html);
 }
});
}
```

```html
<input onclick="filter(<?= $categprod->id ?>);" type="checkbox">
```

Y en el controlador recibo los datos para pasar al Modelo:

```html
function PaginacionData(){
  $condicion = array();
  $condicion['buscar']['categ'] = $this->input->post('categoriadata');
  // Busco datos en el modelo pasando las condiciones
  $data['productos'] = $this->producto_model->getDatos($condicion);
  //Cargo ala vista
  $this->load->view('productos/paginacion-data', $data, false);
}
```

En el modelo recibo y trato de obtener los datos con WHERE_IN de la siguiente manera:

```html
function getDatos($params = array()){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('productos');
  $this->db->where_in('category_id',array($params['buscar']['categ']));
  $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

Comment: disculpa y cual es el error concreto que recibes?

Comment: El resultado muestra solo el primer ID ingresado de la categoria mendiante onclick desde la vista Ejemplo: primero categoria a filtrar es con ID=10 y quiero agregar para filtrar otra categoria con ID=2 o 15 por decir y no muestra de los 3 ID ingr5esados medioante array al modelo sigue mostrando en el resultado el primer ID ingresado mediante AJAX

Comment: recuerda que el array debe ser simple y no asociativo, algo asi: `$names = array('valor1', 'valor2', 'valor3');` por otro lado, verifica que los datos estén llegando todos, si estas usando radios, el name debe ser distinto para cada uno, con los checkbixes debes agregar corchetes al nombre `name="id[]"` de esa manera te debería enviar un array,  y eso no lo estas haciendo, serializa los campos de la id antes de agregarlos a la petición post

Comment: Los datos llegan al controlador normal como se quiere valor1, valor2, valor3 pero no se como saber si al modelo esten llegando de forma correcta

Comment: Simple, ve depurando cada paso, por ejemplo, imprime lo que llega al controlador, si esta bien, imprime lo que llega al modelo y de allí partes a solventar